# excel dropdown list if cell is colored

Tags: excel, colors, dropdown

I need some help, coz Im not an expert.
CASE:

I have 10 workers in my little company, I want to make a schedule for them.
Each month they send me which days are they available for work.

I made table (2) for this. Verticaly the names, horizontally the days 1-31.
If someone is available the cell for that day is EMTPY or GREEN, otherwise RED.

So, I want table (1) the "final schedule" to contain a dropdown list for each day with the AVAILABE workers so I can choose. (maybe the choosen ones cell automatically goes red on specific day in table (2).  Is this possible, or partly possible? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcqYR.jpg)
Last thing: is it possible to add a colordropdown option for the cells?

Answer (score 0):

i will give you a better idea. Goto ur mail and click on Google Drive then add a new sheet. 
in that sheet u can add employee names and u can show them datewise, is they are availbale or not with desired colors.

am also attached a pic for easy understand.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTN4O.png)

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately this is more complex sheet, and I need help for that part. I tried and understand what you described. This drop down question is able to save hours every month for me and my team. Again: thank you!